# Modifying code in a website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a basic ASP.NET website running under IIS.  I didn't `publish` it, so it's not precompiled or anything.

I was under the impression that if I modify any of the code under any *.aspx.cs file, the site would compile just-in-time and be updated to show those changes.

However, that's not the case.  It doesn't reflect my changes and still runs the old code which is in the websitename.dll under the bin folder.  Removing that file throws an error.

Is there a way to dynamically modify and run code in an IIS website?

EDIT:  the .aspx files do reflect any modifications, it's the .aspx.cs that doesn't work.

Comment: Look in the .aspx files, where do they point for their code behind?

Comment: `CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MySite.Default"`

Comment: It's been a while since I did webforms, but that looks like a @Page directive from a Web Application, not a Web Site. With a Web Application the code-behind needs to be compiled and deployed as an assembly in the bin folder.

Comment: You're right, it is a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your site is an ASP.NET web application instead of a website. Look at the .aspx file.

In a web application it looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication._Default" %>
```

In a web site it looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

So if your aspx contains `CodeFile` directive, changes to the code behind will be dynamically picked up.

If it is a web application, you can get rid of the code behind files and any changes would require recompilation.

Comment: BTW, web application projects are better. Web site "projects" are very strange and have a set of problems that only they have.